# pint: Magnitude of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pint

I am trying to print a numpy array without its units. I have done this succesfully if a quantity is a float (e. g. `3 *ureg.milliampere`). On the other hand, in case of an array, I cannot have the array returned . Does anybody know how to to return the whole array without the units?

```
import pint
ureg=pint.UnitRegistry()
i=3*ureg.milliampere 
print (i.magnitude)
>>>3 # This is what I expect

x=np.random.rand(6)*ureg.milliampere`
print (x.magnitude)

>>>1 # I want to have the array returned, instead.
```

Comment: Your last line returns an array on my machine...

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Numpy 1.15.1 and Pint 0.8.1

Comment: I have Numpy 1.15.0 and Pint 0.8.1 and the last line prints an array in IPython 6.5.0 with Python 3.7.0 on my machine as well. Do you still get this error? Which Python version are you using?